# Optimization of a bounded discontinuous function

Tags: optimization, computational-mathematics, continuity

Suppose an unknown function of real variables, 
$f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times ...\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where it takes multiple inputs $x_1,x_2,...,x_{35}$ and return a value $y$.

Suppose that $|f|$ is bounded by an **unknown** large number $M$ on interval $x_i\in [0,1]$ for $i=1,2,...35$.

We thus investigate $f$ in $[0,1]^{35}$.
Suppose that $f$ has large but finite discontinuous in $[0,1]^{35}$, i.e. such as $x_1$ has discontinuous at $0.1,0.001,0.005,0.5,...,0.9$ when $x_j\in [0,0.000001]$ for $j=2,...,35$.

Question:

What's the quickest and most efficient way to estimate $M$ and optimize $f$ in $[0,1]^{35}$?

Because we don't know the exact form of the function, simple analytical approach does not apply. However, because the function is bounded and continuous in very small regions across $[0,1]^{35}$, this may created some sort of dependency. Thus a analytical computational solution may be possible.

However, because of those discontinuous, approach such as newton's does not work well. Further, because of the high dimension in domain, simple trust zone methods does not work well.

I thought about grouping, i.e. splits 35 dimension into 15 initial one(region I), 15 in the middle(region II), and 15 at the end(region III), 
then select 10 points of largest outcome from region I while fix region II, III, then select 10 points of largest outcome from region II while fix region I, III, 
then select 10 points of largest outcome from region II while fix region I, III, 
then I, II, III,... and optimize them in a circle.

I also thought about using assumed statistical distribution to select the points to further accelerate the this process. Further, because the discontinuous is finite, say $N$, we may be able to develop a statistics of $M$ much faster than we optimized the value.

What's the quickest and most efficient way to estimate $M$ and optimize $f$ in $[0,1]^{35}$?

Comment: If the only knowledge is that it is bounded, the only algorithm that gives the true solution is to evaluate $f$ at all points in its domains (which using finite precision is a finite number of points, but large). This is because the function can be $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq p$ and $f(p)=M$. The only way to determine which point is $p$ is to test all of them.

Comment: @user647486 just thought about that, add a condition:"To further simplify the question, one may assume the "volume" of the smallest discontinuous region is bounded by a finite number $a>0$." Thus we don't need to think about singular values, and we know the values solution exists. the original question only assumed $a>0$ exists, but we can suppose $a$ is a known number thus the solution is guaranteed to exists in finite many steps.

Comment: That doesn't change the problem. Since it only changes what 'precision' means in the comment above. The only thing that you can hope for is to make a guess for $M$. This is, using some heuristic optimization algorithm.

Comment: @user647486 The function does not contain singular value such as $f(p)=1$ at $p$ and $0\in [0,1]\setminus \{p\}$. Otherwise it's boring and no solutions.

Comment: What do you know about the function then? You said it is discontinuous. Until you properly pose the question, there is no other approach that an heuristic.

Comment: @user647486 Bounded, unknow,  discontinuous at finite places but do not exists singleton value(i.e. in one dimensional cases, if discontinuous happen, at $a$, for $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ there will be continuous.) The input is in a finite region with high dimensions. To simply the question and guarantee a solution, $a>0$ the smallest region of continuous exists and known.(i.e. in one dimensional cases, let $A$,$B$ be any two points where discontinuous happened, $|A-B|>a$)

Comment: Nothing has changed. Instead of taking $p$ to be a point, divide the domain in boxes of size $a$ and take $f$ to be $0$ in all boxes except for one of the boxes in which it is $M$. As I said, all you are saying is information that will determine what 'precision' means.

Comment: That case was specifically excluded, just divide the space into $(1/a)^{35}$ pieces, then the result is done.